# Main class not found error while creating Maven Project in Scala IDE

Tags: xml, eclipse, scala, maven

There are a lot of posts about this error.  Some of them worthy to mention are [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953468/scala-project-wont-compile-in-eclipse-could-not-find-the-main-class) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179677/scala-main-class-not-found-in-eclipse-ide). But I think my case is different my main class is running before adding dependencies in XML and soon as I do that I get error `Error: Could not find or load main class example.test123`
I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwSwkAHXtxQ&t=502s) video link to try basic example in Scala using Spark.I did following:

Step 1: Created the simple project `testalpha`

Step 2: a) Right click on the project name>> Go to configure>> **Add scala nature**

b) Copy the XML code from [maven-repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/2.1.0) paste this in `pom.xml` file. **Not to forget to right click on Scala Library Container and change scala version to 2.10.6**

Step 3: Add a folder `scala` such that we have `src/main/scala`

Step 4: Create a package `example` under `src/main/scala`. In this package Create a simple scala object and define `main` method to print `hello`. My question is:

If I don't add any dependencies in XML. It prints `hello`. But as soon as I add the dependencies I get this error `Error: Could not find or load main class example.test123`.

Does anyone have any idea about this?
Screenshot to show project structure:
[image]
Screenshot showing printing of `hello`

[image]
My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.scalaproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>testalpha</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>testalpha</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Code Snippet:

```
package example

object test123 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    print("Hello")
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide also your code-snippet

Comment: This error generally come when you use class instead of object, if you want to execute your main method, you must use Scala object.

Comment: Kaushal I am using Scala Object

Comment: I have this same issue now and its bothering me. I was actually getting a good uber jar with main scala class/object. But after I did a Maven->Update Project, the package disappeared and build no longer included main class. An other ideas are welcome. Glad your fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the solution.Instead of directly downloading the scala-ide for eclipse from [here](http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html) make sure you download eclipse separately first from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?).I guess there is still some version issue or some other bug which is why this [scala-ide](http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html) was not generating any class files. May that was the reason why it was unable to figure out the main class(quite surprising to see the target folder empty even after build).Anyways moving on, next you need need to install scala-plugin for newly downloaded eclipse-ide. You can do this as Window>>Eclipse-Marketplace>>Type scala>> Install.

Once it is installed we can follow the standard procedures to create the projects and then it works fine. I have posted relevant issue in the [mailing-list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user) of eclipse as well.